# Oracle developer suite 10g Multilingual support

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am working on Oracle Forms 10g application.
The application was developed in Oracle Forms 6i and Oracle 10g, so i upgraded that application to Oracle Forms 10g and Report 10g with Oracle Express 10g.

Problem is application was design in Saudi Arabi, NLS_LANG  = "ARABIC_SAUDI_ARABIA.AR8MSWIN1256", so forms developer and runtime give all the errors message  in arabi and i don't now arabi.
Is there any way to fix this issue?
I want to read the error in English in forms developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do that using Oracle [TranslationHub 11g](http://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/198892_en-gb.pdf) or [TranslationHub 9i](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/documentation/translationhuboverview-129288.pdf).

If you have Oracle Developer Suite installed then TranslationHub should be installed by default, for a elaborate manual and how to use, go to

> Start menu > All Programs > Oracle- Developer Suite > Forms Developer > TranslationHub Help

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The language of the oracle error message displayed is defined by the NLS_LANGUAGE of your oracle home. Teh first part of the NLS_LANG setting specifies the language, the second the local setting and the third the character set. I have not personally worked with Arabic NLS settings but I have similar problem working with Scandinavian NLS settings. I fixed it by changing the first part of the NLS_LANG setting to AMERICAN. Your could try something like "AMERICAN_SAUDI_ARABIA.AR8MSWIN1256"

In windows the NLS_LANG setting can easily be changed by opening regedit and locate your oracle home somewhere under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE.